# How to ignore all inputs that is less than the value of the first argument and then pass to array/function? (C language)

Tags: c, arrays, linux, parameters, arguments

C language - Linux 
I am new to C and need some help. For this code that I'm working on, I need a way to ignore all inputs that is less than the value of the first argument.

For example, if the user executes the program by: ./file 3 2 5 6 7

Then it will ignore 2 because it is less than the value of the 1st argument which is 3. The other numbers will then be read to an array which will passed to  function.

I used a for loop for this, but not sure where to go from here. I would appreciate any feedback.

```
void function(int arr[]) 
{
   /* some code */
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
int arr[100];

for(int i=0; i < argc; i++) 
{   
   /* if value of arguments is greater than value of argv1 */
   if (argv[i] > argv[1])
   {
      /* pass value  of argument(s) to array named arr */
      arr[i] = argv[i]; 

      /* pass array to function */
      function(arr);
   }
/* other code */
}
```

Comment: `argv[i] > argv[1]` compares pointers address.  Certainly does not meet the coding goal.

Answer (score 1):

By convention, `argv[0]` is the name by which the program is invoked.

In addition `argv` is a pointer to an array of character strings....since you want to store the arguments as integers, you will need to handle this before the comparison (what if the argument contains 10?) and assignment to the int array.

Since the question reads "*I need a way to ignore all inputs that is less than the value of the first argument.*"

One solution would be.....Hope this helps......

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>//for atoi

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int arr[100];
  int j = 2;//counter for argv
  int i = 1;//constant for the first argument in argv
  int k = 0;//counter for the int array(arr)

  for(i; j < argc;j++) 
  {   
    if(atoi(argv[i]) > atoi(argv[j]))//compare first argument with the remaining
       continue;
    else
    {
       arr[k] = atoi(argv[j]);//assign to int array
       k++;
    }
   } 
  /* pass array to function */
  function(arr);
}
```

In addition, `k` would contain the count of numbers inserted in the array `arr`. You could use this count when passing `arr` to the function.....

Comment: Suggest passing `k` into `function()` to indicate the count.

Comment: I agree, an elegant solution.....didn't want to make much changes to how the OP had conceptualized the solution.......

Comment: Have included your suggestion.....appreciate your feedback!!!

Answer (score 0):

the loop is good but as far as I understood you need to call the function without the '2' in the array (given your example)
So, first finish the loop and than hand over the array to the function. 
for handing over the array you are actually using a pointer.

```
void function(int* arr) 
{
   /* some code */
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  int arr[100];

  for(int i=0; i < argc; i++) 
  {   
    /* if value of arguments is greater than value of argv1 */
    if (argv[i] > argv[1])
    {
      /* pass value  of argument(s) to array named arr */
      arr[i] = argv[i]; 
    }
  }

  /* pass array to function */
  function(arr);
  /* other code */
}
```

please remark that the 'function(...)' needs to check for the end of the array by itself. You could improve this by additionally handing over the length of the new array.

Comment: Hello Christian, in `if (argv[i] > argv[1])`, wouldn't `argv[i]` be the name of the program, since `i` is initialized as `0`.....the first optional argument is `argv[1]`......

Comment: In addition `argv` is a pointer to an array of `character` strings...wouldn't the command-line arguments, then, be assigned as characters to an integer array in the line `arr[i] = argv[i];`.....

Comment: `argv[i] > argv[1]` compares pointer  addresses, not their `int` conversion of the strings.